# Trying to Insert contents of text files into an Oracle table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have about 500 Linux scripts.  I am trying to insert the source code from each script into an Oracle table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "SCRIPT_CODE" (
    "SCRIPT_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "CODE_LINE" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "CODE_TEXT" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
)
```

I was using a (painful) manual Excel solution.  Opening each script and pasting the code into a column.  I ran into difficulties and switched gears.

I decided to change the table and place the entire source code from each script into a CLOB field….

```sql
CREATE TABLE "SCRIPT_CODE_CLOB" (
    "SCRIPT_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "CODE_TEXT" CLOB
)
```

Here is the Insert code that I wrote:

```sql
set define off;
Declare Code Clob;
Script Varchar2(100);
sql_exec varchar2(1000);
Begin
Script := 'Some Script Name'
;
Code := '
[pasted code here]
'
;

sql_exec := 'INSERT INTO SCRIPT_CODE_CLOB VALUES (:1, :2)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(sql_exec) USING Script, Code;
COMMIT;
End;
```

This was going great until I ran into a script that had 1,700 lines of code.  When I pasted all the code in and ran the script, it gave me:

```sql
ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

I am looking for a better way of doing this.  Is it possible to Import the files somehow and automate the process?

There are some external tables in the Oracle database, and I can get to the folder location that they point to.

Thanks very much for any assistance.
-   Steve

Environment:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production 
Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.0.2.15, Build 15.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to insert into the clob, you need to use the DBMS_LOB functions (specifically DBMS_LOB.WRITE) rather than reading it into a variable and passing that directly into your insert statement. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999593) for the package. You'll need to read the data into a buffer or temporary lob and then use that in the insert.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris. I ended up implementing the manual Excel process. For other's who might read this...  Discovered that pasting code into Excel broke it into multiple columns, so I added a concatenated column that stuck them all together.  For each code section, I did an autonumber formula to get the line numbers.  After that, I spit it out into a csv and imported right into Oracle.  Thanks for your help Chris